# my car fuel consuption is very high!

Tags: mitsubishi

my car is mitsubishi spacewagon 99model , I change the engine from GDI to small 4G63 & the fuel consuption of the vehicle is very high, I've change the nozzle,airflow meter, fuel pump & ICU,  please what can I do again?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Let me get this straight... Your '99 Space Wagon originally had Gasoline Direct Injection and you replaced it with a 4G63? How high is the fuel consumption? What do you think it should be?

Comment: Yes,I replace with another gasoline injection but smaller than the formal gasoline injection.I don't no what the problem is that's I threw it open

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information before anyone can answer this - how high is the fuel consumption? what was it before the conversion? what would you expect it to be after - what would it be in a similar car with the same engine?